# How can I use a media field in a custom form?

Tags: 8, forms, media

I tried something below, which is not working in drupal 8.

```
$form['upload_documents'] = [
  '#type'          => 'media',
  '#tree'          => TRUE,
  '#title'         => t('Upload your documents'),
  '#default_value' => ['fid' => $default_value],
  '#media_options' => [
    'global' => [
      'file_extensions' => 'pdf doc docx',
      'types'           => ['document'],
    ],
  ],
  '#attached'      => [],
  '#extended'      => TRUE,
  '#required'      => TRUE,
];
```

Comment: Have you tried this one: https://www.drupal.org/project/media/issues/1510012#comment-9773961

Comment: Yes I tried that, which is for Drupal 7 , and it is not working

Comment: Scanning through the core code it seems a little bit that `'#type' => 'media'` form elements are not there yet in D8.

Comment: Media isn't a form element.

Comment: @Kevin - at least in D7 contrib it seemed to provide a form element.

Comment: As far as I can tell, its not listed here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to create the media autocomplete field like below.

```
// $id is your media ID.
$media = \Drupal\media_entity\Entity\Media::load($id); 

$form['upload_doc'] = [
  '#type'          => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type'   => 'media',
  '#default_value' => $media,
];
```

Answer (score 4):

There is also module ([Media Library Form API Element](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_library_form_element)) that supports  this kind of implementation:

```
$form['image'] = [
  '#type' => 'media_library',
  '#allowed_bundles' => ['image'],
  '#title' => t('Upload your image'),
  '#default_value' => NULL|1,
  '#description' => t('Upload or select your profile image.'),
];
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This does work. It's odd that Media is a part of core and yet we have to use a contrib module for this, but that's Drupal.

Comment: So, how do you render it back out? I have a page preprocess function and I need to pass along the media to the template.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8, you can use the entity browser.

A simple example of available options:

```
$form['upload_documents'] = array(
  '#type' => 'entity_browser',
  '#entity_browser' => $entity_browser_id, // e.g. 'document_browser'
  '#cardinality' => $cardinality, // e.g. 1
  '#selection_mode' => $selection_mode, //e.g. 'selection_append'
  '#default_value' => $entities,
  '#custom_hidden_id' => $hidden_id,

);
```

In the form submit, it leaves the entity IDs of the selected entities in a hidden field.